# ProjectReference conflicts Transitive PackageReference

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nuget-spec, conflicting-libraries, packagereference

This question has been discussed on several topics here but I can't find a solution for my case.

I have a library project I'm working on. Let's call it `LibraryProject`.

To test and validate it during the development process, I have another project in my vs solution. Let's call it `LibraryProject.TestService`.

The `Library.TestService` references the `LibraryProject` with a `ProjectReference`. It allows me to locally test the update of the `LibraryProject` without uselessly creating a nuget package and import it on a test project.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\LibraryProject\LibraryProject.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `LibraryProject` is part of a core package that I import on all my projects. Let's call it `SharedLibraries`.
I specified in the `SharedLibraries.config.nuspec` that the `LibraryProject` is a dependency and is required :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency id="LibraryProject" version="1.0.13" />
</dependencies>
```

So, everything is fine, when I include the `SharedLibraries` package, it also includes the `LibraryProject` as a Transitive Package.

But to make my life easier, my `LibraryProject.TestService` also includes the `SharedLibraries` package, and so it also includes the `LibraryProject` as a Transitive Package.

Now, when I try to run my project, I get a conflict error :

> An assembly with the same simple name 'LibraryProject' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references (for example, '[...].libraryproject\1.0.13\lib\net70\LibraryProject.dll') or sign them to enable side-by-side execution.

And before this, I also get a warning :

> warning MSB3243: Unable to resolve conflict between "LibraryProject, Version=1.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" and "LibraryProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null". Arbitrarily choosing "LibraryProject, Version=1.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

The version 1.0.0.0 is obviously my local project. The one I want to include.

Unfortunately I can't override or even remove a Transitive Dependency.

How could I solve this conflict please ?